# Flash Builder iOS export release Error Invalid format versionLabel

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, export, builder

I have been releasing my App (Desktop, Android & iOS) until today. without any visible reason, I keep getting the same error message:

> Error occurred while packaging the application: 
>   Warning:  `Invalid format specified <versionLabel> tag`. Ignoring its value.

I can release Desktop and Android packages but not iOS!

Logically, the error message is wrong.

I am working on Windows 10 and Flash Builder 4.7.

Please help!

Comment: You have an **app.xml**? What number are you putting in **versionLabel** section of the xml? Also did you recently upgrade your AIR SDK then error started?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In fact, it was a wrong error message. I removed the versionLabel value, then I tried to package and I got the right error message: Certificate expired. Now I can package like before!

Answer (score 2):

I don't package for iOS but from a quick research of your problem...

(1)
If you are putting version number as `1.2.3.4.5` etc then it must actually be **only** as : `1.2.3`

> From AIR 18 SDK onwards,
>
> - the value of **versionLabel** is mapped to `CFBundleShortVersionString`
> - the value of **versionNumber** is mapped to `CFBundleVersion`.

See Apple documentation : [**`CFBundleShortVersionString`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-111349) and also [**`CFBundleVersion`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364)

Pay attention to *"The release version number is a string composed of three period-separated integers"* and the warning *"The value for this key is different from the value for `CFBundleVersion`"*

(2) Try updating to the latest AIR SDK (sometimes these issues are already fixed in new version).

Answer (score 1):

My issue is solved.

I removed the `versionLabel` value, then I tried to package again and I got the right error message:

> Certificate expired.

From there onwards (make new certificate) I can package like before.